# Switch for running single unit test vs multiple using Karma

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm currently in the process of writing unit tests using the Karma/Jasmine combo and was wondering if there were a way to specify a single `spec` file to test vs running all of the `spec` files according to the `files` array in the `karma.conf.js` file.

I want to do something like a switch. If I am in my current component folder which contains `.html | .css | .ts | .spec` files, I only want to run the single `spec` file. Otherwise, run all of my spec files.

For example, let's say I want to run a single `spec` file in my component folder for my Angular application. How can I, in my `karma.conf.js` file specify this, can I do something like:

```
files: [
    { pattern: path.resolve(__dirname, '.spec.ts'), watched: true }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always just added f in front of describe and f in front of it.